# How to choose a Threshold for Peaks over Threshold method in R

Tags: r, statistics, quantitative-finance, risk-analysis

I have a data set of financial data, and have made it into log returns, so all data is between -1 and 1.

I am trying to use the following code:

```
getSymbols("^IXIC",from="2016-11-11",to="2018-11-08")
index<-as.vector(IXIC$IXIC.Close)
logret <- diff(log(index))
```

To plot different thresholds using packages

```
library("ismev")
library("evir")
gpd.fitrange(logreturns, umin=0,umax=1)
```

but it gives me an error, and I have no idea how to otherwise code how to choose an appropriate threshold. How can one choose an appropriate threshold?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the `tcplot` function from the `POT` package. It draws a threshold choice plot, i.e. it estimates the scale and shape parameters for different values of the threshold. 
You can then use these plots to obtain a good threshold: a good threshold is characterized by stable estimates with low variance.

```
POT::tcplot(logret, which = 1, nt = 25, u.range = range(logret)* c(1, 0.99), ask = F)
POT::tcplot(logret, which = 2, nt = 25, u.range = range(logret)* c(1, 0.99), ask = F)
```

The first function plots a threshold choice plot with respect to the scale parameter, the second one with respect to the shape parameter. `nt` specifies the number of points in the plot and `u.range` can be specified according to you data.

Comment: I get this:  Error in gpdmle(data, u[i], corr = TRUE, ...) : no data above threshold
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In gpdmle(data, u[i], corr = TRUE, ...) :
  observed information matrix is singular; passing std.err.type to ``expected''
2: In gpdmle(data, u[i], corr = TRUE, ...) :
  observed information matrix is singular; passing std.err.type to ``expected''
3: In gpdmle(data, u[i], corr = TRUE, ...) :
  observed information matrix is singular; passing std.err.type to ``expected''

Comment: my mistake, use `u.range = range(large_drops) * c(1, 0.99)` instead.